# JS code works only if placed in body

Tags: jquery, html

```
$("#btnCon").click(function() {
    $('#con').slideToggle('slow');
    $('.tgg:not(#con)').hide(); 
});
```

When I place this code in the head of html - it doesn't work.
In the body - it works.
In a separate file - it doesn't work.
Where is the secret ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it work in head do this :

```
$(function(){
  $("#btnCon").click(function() {
    $('#con').slideToggle('slow');
    $('.tgg:not(#con)').hide(); 
  });
});
```

The problem was that you were looking for the element with id `btnCon` before it was ready. The usual solution is to embed the code in this callback that jQuery calls when the DOM is ready.

But note that even while using `$(function(){ ... });` is always recommended, the best practice is generally to put your code either

- in a separate javascript file
- in a script element at the end of the body

Comment: Thanks. Solved, but... I hope i will understand

Comment: "in a separate javascript file" and "in a script element at the end of the body" are not disjoint. You can do both. Also I can't see any argument in favor of the end of body.

Comment: *"...while using `$(function(){ ... });` is always recommended..."* By whom? If you control where the `script` elements go, there's no reason to use the `ready` event.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It helps prevent bugs arising from accessing DOM elements that are past the script that the script used to not use. That is, when the script or DOM is evolving, subtle bugs may arise.

Comment: In fact *I* don't always use it, and I agree with @T.J.Crowder. But I recommend this practice to newcomers and obviously [jQuery's tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery) does the same. The good thing when people ask question starting with `$(function(){` is that you don't need to ask them if they waited for the DOM to be loaded ^^

Comment: @JanDvorak The point he is making is that the "best practice" is to place the scripts before the closing body tag which in turn makes listening for the domready event obsolete.

Comment: @JanDvorak: That's why I say "just before the closing `</body>` tag" every time I mention it. It would be very weird to put content underneath the final `script` tag in a document. :-) But `ready` is largely harmless, it just delays things a small bit.

Comment: @dystroy, when i placed my question, after pressing the enter, you answer was on screen after 3-4 seconds. How you can this ?

Comment: Now the question is : would this answer be better for OP without "even while using $(function(){ ... }); is always recommended" ?

Comment: @Alegro In the kit of any SO user with more than 5k rep, there is a time machine.

Answer (score 4):

> When I place this code in the head of html - it doesn't work.
>   In the body - it works.
>   In a separate file - it doesn't work.

It'll work in a separate file if you put the `script` tag including the file at the end of the body, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

The reason it isn't working is that when it's in the `head`, the code runs right away, and the elements don't exist yet, so the handler doesn't get hooked up.

The right answer here is to put the `script` tag for the code right at the end. This is what's advocated by the [YUI team](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) and the [Google closure library team](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41). You'll also see people using jQuery's [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) event for this and putting scripts in `head`, and that does work, but there's no need to do that if you control where the `script` tags go.

So in short:

This works:

```
<body>
...content...
<script>
/* ...code... */
</script>
</body>
```

and this works:

```
<body>
...content...
<script src="/the/script/file.js"></script>
</body>
```

and this works:

```
<head>
...
<script>
jQuery(function($) { // <== This is a shortcut for `ready`
    /* ...code...*/
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
...content...
</body>
```

and this works **if** the code in the script file is inside a `ready` handler:

```
<head>
...
<script src="/the/script/file.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...content...
</body>
```

Comment: note that not using the `ready` event may arise in subtle bugs by novice programmers that don't feel the need to keep the `script` at the end (or, more likely, not place anything past the `script`).

Comment: @JanDvorak: Sorry, didn't follow that sentence.

Comment: I mean, if you don't use `ready`, novice programmers are more likely to introduce bugs into your code.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Teach them to put new content above the script tag. I don't find "something might hypothetically go wrong later" a very convincing argument. :-) But `ready` is mostly harmless, just delays things a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Try it in document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnCon").click(function() {
        $('#con').slideToggle('slow');
        $('.tgg:not(#con)').hide(); 
    });

});
```

Shorthand -

```
$(function () {

    $("#btnCon").click(function() {
        $('#con').slideToggle('slow');
        $('.tgg:not(#con)').hide(); 
    }); 

});
```